# after wp_update_post string displays as 'array'

Tags: php, wordpress

I disabled title and editor support for posts. Therefore I added a function that updates them if not revision. Apart from the assigned arguments, I expect other values not updated like images.

But, it seems to have updated it's value as string('Array'). When and why does a value saved as 'Array' of string type? Also, kindly advise how can I prevent images values not affected when `wp_update_post()` used?

```
 public function saveMetaBox($post_id)
    {

        $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];

        foreach ($_POST as $key=> $value) {

            if (0 === strpos($key, $prefix)) {

                if (isset($_POST[$key]))
                {   
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $_POST[$key]); 
                }
            }

        }

        if (!wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {

            $args = array();
            $args['ID'] = $post_id;
            $args['post_title'] = $_POST[$prefix.'_name'];
            $args['post_name'] = str_replace(' ','-', 
                                 $_POST[$prefix.'_name']);
            //displays correctly
            var_dump(get_post_meta($post_id, 'gallery_image', false));

            remove_action('save_post', array($this, 'saveMetaBox'));
            $post_status = wp_update_post($args);
            if (is_wp_error($post_status)) {
                $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    echo $error;
                }
            }
            //displays incorrrectly
            var_dump(get_post_meta($post_id, 'gallery_image', false));exit;
            add_action('save_post', array($this, 'saveMetaBox'));
        }

    }
```

Output:

[image]